# Fetching from database and maping through array in db column

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs

Sorry if the titel was a bit of or bad.

But the thing is that im fetching from my db and im using map to display each product and i have a selectionbox inside the rendered product where im trying to map from an array in the db.

Im fetching like this:

```
fetch('/api/products')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(allProducts => {
        this.setState({ allProducts });
});
```

My map look like this:

```
{
this.state.allProducts.map(allProducts =>
                            
  <div className="products" key={allProducts.produkt_id}>
                                
  <select name="format">
    <option value="choose_format">choose format</option>
                                        
  </select>

</div>
)
}
```

And in my db the array is stored like this in a column:

[{"car":"audi"},{"car":"bmw"}]

How do i map out the different cars as options or im i doing something wrong and can i store it in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ produkt_id: "123", car: "bwm" , color: [{"color":"audi"},{"color":"bmw"}]}
```

Your render would then be:

```
return this.state.allProducts.map((product) => (
    <div className="products" key={product.produkt_id}>
      <select name="format">
        {product.color.map((colorOption) => (
          <option value={colorOption.color}>{colorOption.color}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: { produkt_id: "123", car: "bwm" , color: [{"color":"red"},{"color":"white"}]}

maybe color in the array i can remove later so it doesnt have to say color twice but this is a better example how i have it now and i want the options to display every color of the car, how can i do that?

Comment: im trying your solution but im getting "TypeError: product.color.map is not a function", do you know why?

Comment: Tells you color is not a array, so it does not have a `.map` function. Debug with console.log.

Comment: Thank you very much, had use JSON.parse(), instead of product.color.map i had to use JSON.parse(product.color).map